# ios certificate wizard , generate

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

ios certificate wizard (generate) results in the error message

> codename one an error occurred communicating whith the server

Please ensure your apple id is active etc. Thanks.

IDE: NetBeans

Desktop: linux mint OS

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a verified paid Apple developer account?

Make sure that you can log into this page: 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action

And actually see the provisioning profiles, that you don't get redirected elsewhere...

Check out [this section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/signing.html).

Comment: thanks shia , i dont have paid Apple developer account .